# textView вертикальное смещение текста, относительно изображения

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

Всем привет. Есть разметка

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/grade_black"
            android:text="@string/star_google_play"
            android:textColor="@color/secondTextColor"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

В итоге получилось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сместить текст к центру картинки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"` или просто   android:layout_gravity="center"

Либо, если `height="match_parent"` (а `height` звездочки = "wrap_content"), можно  `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: спасибо, второй ответ помог